# Pack using overloaded operator

Tags: fortran

I am trying to use the pack function on an array of custom types. I have set up a small module with the type and interface to overload `.eq.`. If I do a simple comparison the overloaded operator appears to work, however when used in the context of a pack function I get an error.

```
!The module

module m_types

  type :: t_property
     character(12) :: key
     logical :: value
  end type t_property

  type(t_property), allocatable, dimension(:) :: properties

  public :: operator(.eq.)
  interface operator(.eq.)
     procedure prop_eq
  end interface operator(.eq.)

contains

  pure function prop_eq(first, second) result(res)
    type(t_property), intent(in) :: first, second
    logical :: res

    if (first%key .eq. second%key) then
       res = .true.
    else
       res = .false.
    end if

  end function prop_eq

end module m_types

! The test program
program textadventure
  use m_types
  implicit none
  type(t_property) :: temp

    allocate(properties(0))

    temp = t_property(key="lit", value=.true.)
    properties = [properties, temp]

    temp = t_property(key="visited", value=.false.)
    properties = [properties, temp]

    temp = t_property(key="lit", value=.false.)
    properties = [properties, temp]

    temp = t_property(key="cold", value=.false.)
    properties = [properties, temp]

    temp = t_property(key="cold", value=.false.)
    properties = [properties, temp]

    print *, properties
    print *,  (properties(4) .eq. temp) ! Succeeds

    print *, size(pack(properties, properties .eq. temp)) ! Fails

    deallocate(properties)

end program textadventure
```

GCC error message

```
Error: Operands of comparison operator ‘.eq.’ at (1) are TYPE(t_property)/TYPE(t_property)
```

The spec says the mask in `PACK` should be a logical scalar which I thought I had provided - can someone point out where I am wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In the comparison for the mask, `properties .eq. temp` you have two objects of `type(t_property)` and you hope to use the function `prop_eq` to provide that defined operation.

However, the first operand `properties` is an array, and the first dummy argument of `prop_eq` is a scalar.  As a result, there is no defined operator `.eq.` available.  You should provide a function to process an array first argument.  One way would be to make `prop_eq` elemental.

Returning an array result from `.eq.` is appropriate: the `mask=` argument to `PACK` should conformable with the array argument (and you don't want it to be scalar).

In the successful comparison `properties(4) .eq. temp` the first operand is scalar.

Comment: Thanks - I modified the function to return an array and it works has expected.

Answer (score 2):

The corrected code for those interested, it now packs as expected.

```
module m_types

  type :: t_property
     character(12) :: key
     logical :: value
  end type t_property

  type(t_property), allocatable, dimension(:) :: properties

  public :: operator(.eq.)
  interface operator(.eq.)
     procedure prop_eq
  end interface operator(.eq.)

contains

  function prop_eq(first, second) result(res)
    type(t_property), intent(in) :: second
    type(t_property), intent(in), dimension(:) :: first
    logical, dimension(:), allocatable :: res
    integer :: i

    allocate(res(0))
    do i=1, size(first)
       if (first(i)%key .eq. second%key) then
          res = [res, .true.]
       else
          res = [res, .false.]
       end if
    end do

  end function prop_eq

end module m_types

program textadventure
  use m_types
  implicit none
  type(t_property) :: temp

    allocate(properties(0))

    temp = t_property(key="cold", value=.false.)
    properties = [properties, temp]

    temp = t_property(key="lit", value=.true.)
    properties = [properties, temp]

    temp = t_property(key="visited", value=.false.)
    properties = [properties, temp]

    temp = t_property(key="lit", value=.false.)
    properties = [properties, temp]

    temp = t_property(key="cold", value=.false.)
    properties = [properties, temp]

    temp = t_property(key="cold", value=.false.)
    properties = [properties, temp]

    print *, size(properties)
    print *,
    print *, pack(properties, mask = properties .eq. temp)

    deallocate(properties)

end program textadventure
```